# Authentication error message in okta login page

Tags: java, session, servlet-filters, okta

I got my okta login page in my application using authorize endpoint.

When there is no user present in okta, error message displays on the page as expected.
When the user is exists in okta, but the user does not belong to a right group, then there is no error message is shown in the page. Its navigating to my application’s servlet doFilter method with error in servlet request.

Now 2 questions.

1. Will there be any session in okta for this user? If so, how do I kill it?
2. Is there any way that I can restrict them in okta login
   page itself?

Please shed some light on these.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, for the first question. User may have an Okta session, but you won't be able to kill it, unless you use management API. To be honest I'm not sure  it's a good idea to kill their session in Okta, only b/c they are not assigned to your application. There might be tons of other apps which user has access to.
2. If you use login with redirect to Okta, then Okta hosted login page would show them standard 403 page (Application is not assigned).  When you use widget (self hosted login page), then Okta doesn't show this error to a user, but rather reflects that in a response to /authorize call